# Need to cast string value representing a 0.XXXX floats to actual number value in PHP

Tags: php, casting, floating-point, numbers

So I am trying to cast a string value of ie: '0.0000143' to actual FLOAT or DECIMAL number value (so it must not be a string after conversion), but the actual number of 0.0000143 as it needs to be sent through some API call and the API requires it to be structured like that and not have an actual string value.

Can anyone help me achieve this (or is it actually even possible to do)?. Since I am out of ideas

To make things more clear, I have tried all the type casting possibilities there are in PHP (it is not working as I do not need something like 1.4E-5 returned to me, but the actual value like 0.0000143).

Comment: Easiest: assuming `$val` is a string representation of a number, `+$val` is a number. So is `(float) $val`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: you could use `floatval()`

Comment: You should show the code you are using, the results it produces and how you need it to be instead.

Comment: Converting it to float `$float = (float)$string;` or `$float = floatval($string);`, you won't get `0.0000143` if you dump the variable, but rather `1.43E-5`, but that is a valid representation of that float.

Comment: using any type casting of floatval() or (float)$variable is just going to spit out the PHP representation of the float ( which could be used later for calculations in a PHP script, but I dont want PHP representation of the float, but the actual 0.xxx value as a number returned to me so that I can send it in a param to the API ).

In terms of code, there is nothing specific, I just have one variable like $amount which has the STRING value of 0.00014 ( entered in an HTML input and returned from the form as a STRING to me ). I would like to cast it to actual 0.00014 as a number

Comment: `1.43E-5` isn't anything specific to PHP.

Comment: we can convert using this function too settype($x, "float");

Comment: _"I do not need something like 1.4E-5"_ - If the API expects a float, then `1.4E-5` should work. That _is_ a float and is identical to what you expect to see. It's simply just how it's represented when it contains that many decimals. If the API can't handle that (which it should be able to), it's the API that's wrong, not that value.

Comment: After your last comment i triple checked the API and it seems it returned the wrong param type because this param goes hand in hand with another params value. So it seems I haven't put a correct value into that other param which is connected with this one ( that should be a float ), which made all of this confusion about me thinking 1.4E-5 was not a correct value to be sent over. Thank you all for your comments, it helped me solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) in order to achieve that:

```
$string = '0.0000143';
$intValue = (int)$string;
$floatValue = (float)$string;
```